# Possible to backup External Disk to Time Capsule regardless which machine it's connected to?

Tags: time-machine, backup, external-disk, time-capsule

Here's the scenario: I have two MacBook Pros (`Foo` and `Bar`), and their drive's are both called `Macintosh HD`. I have a Time Capsule called `Time Capsule`, which is used to back up both `Foo` and `Bar`. I also have an external disk called `Stuff` which I connect to both `Foo` and `Bar`.

Is it possible to have `Stuff` backed up to `Time Capsule` in such a way that regardless of whether `Stuff` is connected to either `Foo` or `Bar`, the same destination on `Time Capsule` is used? I.e. can an external disk connected to two different computers be backed up to the same Time Machine disk without duplication?

Seems like this might be possible with `tmutil` but I haven't been able to figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

well good question and well described. It is possible to BackUp 2 Macbooks `Foo`and `Bar`to **one** TimeMachine Disk.

I had some problems with SnowLeopard but with Mountain Lion it was a lot better and now with Mavericks it is working fine.

So if you have Mavericks installed on both it is no hassle so far in my Envirmonent (have 4 Macbooks and one TimeMachine Disk (in the Network))

Example of may TM Diks

```
TimeMachine
|- Macbook Pro Martin
|- iMac Martin
|- MacPro Martin
|- Macbook Air
```

<sup>Folder has been renamed in this example</sup>

So the Devices are seperated in Folders on your TM Disk.

Comment: Apparently not well described since this is not the question that I asked. I'm fully aware it's possible to backup two different macs to the same Time Capsule. The question is whether it's possible to backup up one external disk, attached to either of two macs to one Time Capsule, without replicating the data of the external disk.